# How to make multiple joins with sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have some tables and i need to join them to main table ChatRomm like this

```
    q = (
        sa.select(m.ChatRoom)
        .select_from(
            sa.join(
                m.ChatRoom, m.ChatRoomUser, m.ChatRoomUser.chatroom_id == m.ChatRoom.id,
            ),
            sa.join(
                m.ChatRoom, m.ChatRoomAdmins, m.ChatRoomAdmins.chatroom_id == m.ChatRoom.id
            )
        )
        .where(m.ChatRoomUser.user_id == user.user_id)
        .limit(page_size)
        .offset(page_size * page_num)
    )
```

but i have a error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.DuplicateAliasError'>: table name "chat_rooms_chatroom" specified more than once
```

but if i do it with one Join it works

```
# it works

    q = (
        sa.select(m.ChatRoom)
        .select_from(
            sa.join(
                m.ChatRoom, m.ChatRoomUser, m.ChatRoomUser.chatroom_id == m.ChatRoom.id,
            )
        )
        .where(m.ChatRoomUser.user_id == user.user_id)
        .limit(page_size)
        .offset(page_size * page_num)
    )
```

So, how can i fix it?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#selecting-orm-aliases